# Simple Win GUI - should I try PowerShell or just stick with HTA?

Tags: windows, user-interface, powershell, hta

knowing what PowerShell can do on a command line I have never learned how to write GUIs with it. Should I?

Or just go back to the good old HTA / VBScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're sure to get varying answers on this depending on folks' background.  I do development work and I'd just as soon write a GUI using C#.  The Visual Studio forms designer is quite nice and doesn't have an equivalent in PowerShell out-of-the-box. And the VS debugger is still much better.  That said, if you want to delve into this area you should check out two PowerShell modules for creating GUI via WPF: [PowerBoots](http://powerboots.codeplex.com/) by Jaykul and WPK in the [PowerShellPack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack) by one of the PowerShell team members.  As you will see when you look at the PowerBoots site, it is definitely possible to do GUI with PowerShell.

Comment: You can use the Visual Studio designer to design your UIs and still use PowerBoots! http://huddledmasses.org/creating-wpf-uis-for-powershell-with-powerboots-and-visual-studio-wpf-designer/

Comment: Thank you for this tip! Would you recommend Powerboots over PrimalForms?

Comment: Both links are not valid anymore...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a simple VB.Net / C# WinForms app.

Comment: @Mike: What is there to elaborate?

Comment: the reasoning behind your answer?

Comment: @Mike: A WinForms GUI will be easier to maintain and expand, and can be more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to package Powershell with a GUI I would suggest looking at [PrimalForms](http://www.primaltools.com/products/screenshots.asp?p=PrimalForms) to quickly prototype your solution.

It has a simple winforms designer powered by powershell scripts.